# Facebook Not Pulling Image OG Image from Shopify

Tags: shopping-cart, facebook-opengraph

Facebook is selectively not pulling OG Images from some of our Shopify product pages despite the og:image being recognized as an object property when debugging the page.

Pages Causing Errors:
http://www.911lights.com/products/mini-laser-sale
http://www.911lights.com/products/starburst-half-phantom (OG Image Not Pulled, Pulls Only Video Graphic)

Pages Working Fine:
http://www.911lights.com/products/dlxt
http://www.911lights.com/products/svp-hh-siren

Comment: This seems to be a common problem over the past couple months. A cloud hosting provider I use has been in touch with Facebook engineering to resolve the issue, but since at least Feb 29 there is no progress.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is related to the image size.   The og:image in is 50x50 with a maximum width:height ratio of 3:1.  Your images on http://www.911lights.com/products/mini-laser-sale and http://www.911lights.com/products/starburst-half-phantom  are both 160 x 41.

Enlarge the actual image on your server (for example: http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0001/0459/products/ULB15_compact.jpg?100254) to 50px high. Also make sure the width is no wider than 150px for a 50px high image.